# iOS App does not take full screen on some iPhones

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I encounter a very strange problem: I got reports from some of my clients that my iPhone App does not show up full screen. It leaves a black bar on top and bottom of the screen. I have got one sample report from a client running iPhone 7 and iOS 12.1. Having the same device and installing the same App (AppStore download, as client does) I cannot reproduce this behaviour. I cannot reproduce it on none of my many devices and iOS versions nor on the simulators. According to AppStore reviews other clients are facing the same behaviour too, but nobody I know can reproduce it. I attached a screenshot taken by one of the clients: [anonymous screenshot of app with black bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJHnb.png)

Edit (due to Question put on hold by guys not understanding the question...): The desired behaviour of course is an App presenting full screen without any black bars

The project is all iOS/XCode default, I am using a LaunchScreen.storyboard with identical settings than a new default XCode Project. I am developing using XCode 9.4, Deployment Target is 9.0, the project is in Swift. I am aware that this was a common problem with the arrival of iPhone 5, but it should no longer occur if using Launch storyboards. None of my other app share this problem.

Does anybody has an advice?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using an old way of determining launch screen. After iOS7 you can define a launch storyboard to create the launch screen. If you use the old method by assets, were you add some images to be used as launch screen, the app 'understands' that is not updated for iOS greater than 7, so, you have to remove these assets [screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jg259.png) and use the launch storyboard. It must fix the top and bottom banners.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is exactly what I already do, I use a storyboard it is configured this way in info.plist.

Comment: OP says pretty clearly that he/she is using a launch storyboard.

Comment: @Caleb after editing, also, you can have the launch storyboard but without reference on general config.

Answer (score 1):

You can add LuanchImage like:

[image]

Then you can set images with the correct sizes for atleast:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I am aware that I can try this, but I never experienced issues using a storyboard launch file before. It does not even occur on all devices, so i'm curious to find out the reason and don't want to workaround the problem.